# mod_rewrite to force SSL for a subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I try to make a redirect from a special folder to a special host.

When somebody enter http://mydomain.com/administrator he should be redirected to https://a-otherdomain.com/mydomain.com/administrator

What I have is this in a .htaccess file in DOCUMENT_ROOT .. but it want work :(

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator(/*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/administrator/(.*)$ https://a-otherdomain.com/mydomain.com/administrator/$1     [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Any Ideas?

**Update:**

now I use this, which works in apache configuration files for the vhost:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://a-otherdomain.com/mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule doesn't match leading slash in a URI.

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^administrator(/.*|)$ https://a-otherdomain.com/mydomain.com/$0 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: dont know why, but rule only works on apache config not on htaccess. now it works - but your RewriteCond it not right, because it redirects all pages - thanks

Comment: `because it redirects all pages` nope look at `RewriteRule ^administrator(/.*|)$` line that will ONLY redirect all URIs starting with text `/administrator/`